# Find the zeros of $f(x) = x^2 - 150 x\log(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, roots

I have to find the zeros of $f(x) = x^2 - 150 x\log(x)$

It is is pretty straightforward to find $x = 0$ because $x(x-150 \log(x)) = 0$, but how can I find the zeros of $x - 150 \log(x)$?

Comment: Unsolvable with algebraic techniques.

Comment: $\log 0$ is undefined.

Comment: Natural log or log base ten?

Comment: No, $x=0$ is not a solution.

Comment: Even though $log(0)$ is undefined, the limit of $x^2 - 150 x log(x)$ is 0 regardless of base (as long as $b >0$ and $b \neq 1$)

Comment: Newton's method with initial guess $x_0 = 1000$: $$x_{n+1}= x_n - \frac{x_n - 150\log\left(x_n\right)}{1-\frac{150}{x_n}}$$ yields after a few iterations  $x = 1042.39083504$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joshua said, this is not solvable by elementary algebra.  But it can be solved using the Lambert W function.  Recall the definition: $$xe^x = y \;\Longleftrightarrow\; x = W(y).$$

Start with $x^2 - 150 x \log x = 0$.  Factor, $x(x-150 \log x) = 0$.  So either $x=0$ or $x-150 \log x = 0$.  For the first case, $x=0$, we should note that $\log 0$ is not defined, but $\lim_{x \to 0^+}(x^2 - 150 x \log x) = 0$.  So $x=0$ is a solution in that sense.

Here is the second case.
$$
x = 150\log x\\
e^x = x^{150}\\
e^{x/150} = x\\
1=xe^{-x/150}\\
\frac{-1}{150}=\frac{-x}{150}e^{-x/150}\\
W\left(\frac{-1}{150}\right) = \frac{-x}{150}\\
-150W\left(\frac{-1}{150}\right)= x
$$
Actually, there are two real branches of the $W$ function, so we get two real solutions
$$
-150W_0\left(\frac{-1}{150}\right) \approx 1.006734134,\qquad
-150W_{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{150}\right) \approx 1042.390835.
$$
Here are two graphs of $x^2 - 150 x\log(x)$.

[image: A]  [image: B]

Here is the classic paper on Lambert W. Perhaps few papers can be labeled "classic" after only 25 years, but this is one!

*Corless, R. M.; Gonnet, G. H.; Hare, D. E. G.; Jeffrey, D. J.; Knuth, D. E.*, [**On the Lambert (w) function**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02124750), Adv. Comput. Math. 5, No. 4, 329-359 (1996). [ZBL0863.65008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0863.65008).

Comment: Are we assuming here that $\log(x)$ is $\ln(x)$ instead of $\log_{10}(x)$?

Comment: @Brian359 ... of course $\log$ is the natural logarithm, this is a mathematics forum.

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to the forum, haven't been on one before. In my experience $\log$ has always been $\log_{10}$ instead of the natural logarithm, and that's only ever been $\ln$, so thank you for the heads up. I'll keep it in mind